# c# Best way to read from XML into class and write back to file

Tags: c#, xml

I have a special XML file which has more attributes but to exemplify what I'm trying to achieve, I've reduced it to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Ref1 Att11="XXX" Att21="YYY" Att31="ZZZ">
 <Ref2 Att12="AAA" Att22="BBB" Att32="CCC">
 <Ref3 Att13="111" Att23="222" Att33="333"/>
 </Ref2>
</Ref1>
```

The file will have many `Ref2` elements but only one `Ref3` on each one.
For some reason, the XML file don't have the `</Ref3>` block but instead, just `/>`.

What should be the best way to read the data from the XML file into a class structure and the reverse, write to a file after?

I have created the classes which are supposed to be used to read the data but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.
I'm not even sure about `Ref3`.
I'm also worried about this simple example when the reality is that the original XML has dozens of Attributes on all `Ref 1, 2 and 3`.

```
public class Ref1
{
    public string Att11 { get; set; }
    public string Att21 { get; set; }
    public string Att31 { get; set; }

    public List<Ref2> ref2;
}

public class Ref2
{
    public string Att12 { get; set; }
    public string Att22 { get; set; }
    public string Att32 { get; set; }

    public Ref3 ref3;
}

public class Ref3
{
    public string Att13 { get; set; }
    public string Att23 { get; set; }
    public string Att33 { get; set; }
}
```

It would be good to have an example to progress further.

Comment: Take a look at something like https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net ?

Comment: Please clarify what you are using now and how much faster you want to get. Also make sure to profile code to confirm that for example disk IO is not already bottleneck in your case. So far post is very broad/opinion based - [edit] it to clarify/narrow down.

Comment: @Caius Jard: Thank you. I wasn't aware this was possible.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov: It wasn't the "how fast" but "how". I wasn't thinking that this could be done using Xml Serialization. I'm sorry for that. Apart from the questions I left for jdweng, it works fine and the answer suits well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not a question about fastest but the best method.  Since your requirements is to serialize and de-serialize then I would recommend using Xml Serialization.  See code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings rSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            rSettings.Schemas = null;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(INPUT_FILENAME, rSettings);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Ref1), string.Empty);

            Ref1 ref1 = (Ref1)serializer.Deserialize(reader );


            XmlWriterSettings wSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            wSettings.Indent = true;
            XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            namespaces.Add("","");
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(OUTPUT_FILENAME, wSettings);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, ref1, namespaces);
        }
    }
    public class Ref1
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Att11")]
        public string Att11 { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("Att21")]
        public string Att21 { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("Att31")]
        public string Att31 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Ref2")]
        public List<Ref2> ref2;
    }

    public class Ref2
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Att12")]
        public string Att12 { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("Att22")]
        public string Att22 { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("Att32")]
        public string Att32 { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Ref3")]
        public Ref3 ref3;
    }

    public class Ref3
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Att13")]
        public string Att13 { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("Att23")]
        public string Att23 { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("Att33")]
        public string Att33 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you very much. I've tried it already even with the big XML and works absolutely fine. When comparing both files, original from read and the copy from write the only differences are the indentation at each element, a space at the end of `Ref3` element `" />` and a space that is removed at the end of `"utf-8"?>`. This shouldn't cause any issue I assume?

Comment: Does the line `[XmlAttribute("XXXXX")]` on each property mean that the properties can have any name we wish and the compiler will look at the Attribute or Element name? What about the order for the attributes when the compiler Reads or Writes, is this in sequence or because it's an XML file this isn't relevant?

Comment: Xml specification ignores spaces and has option for closing tag to contain or not contain the tag name. If you leave the name out of the attributes above the properties the serializer use the property/class name as the default tag name.